# Bridging and routing IPv6 Router Advertisements

Tags: iptables, router, routing, ipv6

I have a bridge called "br01" in which the interfaces "eth1" and "eth0" are participating. There is a rule in the broute table of ebtables that drops RAs when they arrive in the interface eth1, so the eth1 auto-configure itself with this RA, but I want that this same RA go through the eth0 too, in order to distribute this RA to the other network which is on the eth0. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bridge and route packet](http://serverfault.com/questions/281044/bridge-and-route-packet)

Comment: Can you show me the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: Your eth1 interface should *not* be configuring itself with the RA. The br01 interface should be the one with the addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an ebtables rule that drops the packet, why not remove that rule?

Comment: If I remove, the the packet goes to eth0 but not in the eth1, if don't remove, it goes to eth1 but not in the eth0, what I want is to have both interfaces receiving the packet.

Comment: That's not how bridging works.  Once an interface is in a bridge, it no longer functions as an independent interface.

Comment: Yes I know, but I can do that using the target TEE for instance. So it will route the packet to eth1 and then to eth0 again by cloning the packet. But the use of TEE isn't an option in my case.